# How to check if an email address belongs to Gmail

Tags: gmail, contacts, google-api

I'm creating a function uses Google's API to import contacts from a person's gmail account. However I'm aware that many businesses sign up to Google in order to have a more professional domain name( eg. some_name@bislr.com) but still belongs to Gmail.

Is there a way to check for that?

Comment: I updated my answer with another option, potentially more accurate.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Option 1**

if you do a DNS lookup for the MX records on bislr.com, you get the following:

```
$ host -t mx bislr.com
bislr.com mail is handled by 10 aspmx.l.google.com.
bislr.com mail is handled by 20 alt1.aspmx.l.google.com.
bislr.com mail is handled by 20 alt2.aspmx.l.google.com.
bislr.com mail is handled by 30 aspmx2.googlemail.com.
bislr.com mail is handled by 30 aspmx3.googlemail.com.
bislr.com mail is handled by 30 aspmx4.googlemail.com.
bislr.com mail is handled by 30 aspmx5.googlemail.com.
```

Anyone hosting their email Google Apps will have MX records very similar to these. You can do a MX lookup with any common DNS mechanism and test the MX records for Google's most-recommended mail servers - aspmx.l.google.com, alt1.aspmx.l.google.com, and alt2.aspmx.l.google.com, or look for any/all of the servers in this list.

This won't show you anyone who uses an external forwarding/filtering service but it will work for all of the common cases.

**Option 2**

You can connect to a mail server to verify if it will accept mail to a specific address. Using this, we can connect to asmpx.l.google.com and ask it whether an address is a valid Google Mail account.

If you connect to aspmx.l.google.com:25 and send this string (replace the email addresses as appropriate):

```
HELO
MAIL FROM:<ping@mydomain.com>
RCPT TO:<user@theirdomain.com>
```

Google's mail server will respond with a smtp status code, probably a line starting with something like `250 2.1.5 OK` if it's a valid address. This is a cleaner and far more reliable way than simply checking DNS records, and should work as long as you don't get the checking IP blacklisted by using it to send actual spam to gmail.

[Here is a full walkthrough of the process.](http://www.labnol.org/software/verify-email-address/18220/)

Answer (score 2):

You can't be certain.

The MX record check described by @lunixbochs covers most cases, but many corporates will use Postini, which has different domain names.  They might also be using any number of other mail pre-processing engines which will hide the aspmx records.

One other way to check is to see if they have an active domain name:

curl http://www.google.com/a/DOMAINNAME | grep "domain that isn't using Google Apps"

Use your language / library of choice instead of curl to fetch the url...

Comment: I'm not sure why someone would use postini (google's mail filtering engine) on gmail (google's mail filtering engine). I updated mine with a more reliable nonintrusive option. You're likely to get firewalled by Google if you're scraping their error page to scan for valid domains.

Comment: Many businesses do, and the original question mentioned Google Apps specifically.  Whether you'll get the "automated queries" page depends on your traffic levels obviously; for most scenarios this is actually OK unless you're scanning tens of thousands of domains a day.  Your option 2 is better, but requires that you have a known valid email address - which is OK in the scenario described, but might not be in others...

Comment: Scraping a Google login page repeatedly will almost definitely get your usage investigated and blocked, and should not be relied on in a production system